# ASCII to UTF-8 conversion in java

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, struts

i have a problem which i uploaded data using .CSV file format and it read by java class.and i would be store in db.upto now no problem,but when i read the data from db then data contains some special characters.

so please could you help me here

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "please could you help me here"  Please could you find your shift key?  When you do, apply it once at the start of every sentence. and to every use of the word 'I'.  This helps the reader who is trying to help you, and you would not want to make it harder to help, *would you?*

Answer (score 4):

ASCII-7 is compatible with UTF-8. There is nothing you need to do turn turn ASCII-7 into UTF-8 (but it doesn't work the other way)

Comment: You can read ASCII-7 as UTF-8 format.  You can only specify one encoding when you read a file so when you specify "UTF-8" it is "UTF-8" only.  It could still read a file written in another format correctly. (Depending on the format and the characters used)

Comment: we have problem with some characters like frace,and china characters while setting UTF8 format,but its working with ISO8859_1 format. may i know how we solve this problem ?

Comment: That is odd because http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1 is "8-bit single-byte coded graphic character sets — Part 1: Latin alphabet No. 1, is part of the ISO/IEC 8859 series of ASCII-based standard character encodings, first edition published in 1987. It is informally referred to as Latin-1. It is generally intended for “Western European” languages "  UTF-8 supports higher characters like Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

This is an article you should really read.

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Next, to answer your question:

- To *Read* a file encoded with UTF-8, use a `BufferedReader`:

  ```
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
  ```
- To *Write* a file encoded with UTF-8 use a `BufferedWriter`:

  ```
  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
  ```

Make sure that the transmittion of the data through the sockets goes correct.

Comment: No.. Won't compile. It's `InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter`. [Here's](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) a more Java (EE) targeted article. The text file issue is covered [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#TextFiles).

Comment: @BalusC: Indeed! I always mix them up, without IDE.